# mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given

Tags: php

Hi I have been struggling with this query for a while now

I need to get the number of rows inserted into my database table, but I keep getting this error I can't seem to get rid of.

```
$result3=mysql_query("INSERT INTO dest_table.create_info SELECT * from 
Profusion.source_cdr");
$num_rows = array($result3);
$progress=mysql_num_rows($num_rows);
echo $progress;
```

The error I get is

mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given

It will be highly appreciated if I get this resolved

Comment: This happens because you haven't checked how to use that function in the manual and are just trying to guess.

Comment: mysql_- functions are deprecated .. 
Use mysqli or PDO instead!

Comment: WTH are you casting to an array...

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the resource not the array.

```
$result3=mysql_query("INSERT INTO dest_table.create_info SELECT * from 
Profusion.source_cdr");
$progress=mysql_num_rows($result3);
echo $progress;
```

But since you are using INSERT you should read the manual and use mysql_affected_rows() because mysql_num_rows() only works with SELECT and SHOW.

http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

```
$result3=mysql_query("INSERT INTO dest_table.create_info SELECT * from 
Profusion.source_cdr");
$progress=mysql_affected_rows();
echo $progress;
```

Comment: oh I see, but the problem is I still get a -1 answer if I ask for the number of rows affected, the thing is I want the number of rows in the affected table so that I can pass them into a progress bar that I have created. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: If you get -1 then your sql query failed. Debug this by doing:

$result3=mysql_query("INSERT INTO dest_table.create_info SELECT * from 
Profusion.source_cdr") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Will this equate to an integer value that I can pass into my progress bar to get the percentage.

Comment: Again the reason for getting -1 from mysql_affected_rows() is that you SQL query failed e.g. it contains errors. So of course 0 rows were affected because the query is probably illegal by some syntax issues.

Hence your first approach should be debugging your sql query by asking mysql_error() as i stated before. 

After you fixed your query you can use mysql_affected_rows() properly

Comment: yes I debugged it there seems to be an error here Thread stack overrun: 6312 bytes used of a 131072 byte stack, and 128000 bytes needed. Use 'mysqld -O thread_stack=#' to specify a bigger stack.

Comment: there must be something wrong with my table, I'll let you know just now. thanks tuxmania

Comment: It worked you guys helped alot, thank you very much, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

When using an `INSERT` statement, `mysql_query()` doesn't return an array. It returns `true` on success or `false` on failure. Use `mysql_affected_rows()`.

For example:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (field1,field2) VALUES ('foo', 'bar')");
$num_affected_rows = mysql_affected_rows();

echo $num_affected_rows;

//output: 1
```